# average of prime numbers program

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to calculate the average of the prime numbers between 1 to 10 and I have written a program which is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int i, j, sum = 0, count = 0;
    loop1: 
        for(i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            for(j = i - 1; j > 1; j--)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    goto loop1;
                }
            }
            sum = sum + i;
            count++;
        }
        printf("The avg:%d", (sum / count));
        return 0;
}
```

Please help me whether the program is correct.

Comment: have you tried running it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you do not make a habit of using`goto:` statements. Your program is incorrect. Here, when the statement

```
if(i % j == 0)
```

returns true, the`goto:` statement takes control to the beginning of the parent `for` loop and the loop will run from start again. This way, you will never get your desired output. As per your question, your solution is wrong. A modified approach is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
     int i, j, sum = 0, count = 0,flag;
     for(i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
     {    
         flag=0;
         for(j = i - 1; j > 1; j--)
         {
             if(i % j == 0)
             {
                 flag=1;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(flag==0)
         {
              sum = sum + i;
              count++;
         }

     }
     printf("The avg:%d", (sum / count));
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float sum = 0, count = 0, average;
    for(int i=2; i<11; i++){
        for(int j=2; j<=i; j++){
            if(j==i){
                sum+=i;
                count++;
            }else if(i%j==0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    average=sum/count;
    printf("Average = %.2f", average);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can actually optimize it by a serious factor as the test for a prime number does not need to test division by numbers greater than half of the to be tested number; and similarly, aside of 2, there are no even prime numbers in existence (as they can be divided by 2 ...).

Comment: This is very true, it was done just as a quick solution whilst procrastinating from doing my own homework.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Correct" ?

If correct to you means that it works: well that's easy to verify for yourself.

If correct means that you are hitting the best practices, well then, nope, you missed them I'm afraid.

goto: about the most easy of all "do not use that" signs.

A "better" approach would be to write a function that tests if a number is a prime or not.